# get counter value int from method that return a bool and return to browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to work out how I can get the value of a counter in a method that is inside a foreach loop.

I have thought about delegates but I cannot work out how to do that.

My method is with all irreverent code removed

```
public static bool ReadExcelFile(string str1, int Id, out int tCount)
{
    int primaryCounter = 0;                    

    //Insert new items
    foreach (var item in excelList)
    {                
        primaryCounter++;                                
    }

    return true;
}
```

I then have a ActionResults which I use for the jquery polling

```
public ActionResult InsertPolling()
{
    int currentCount = //How to get value of counter        
    string pollingMessage = $"Inserted {currentCount}  items";
    return Json(pollingMessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My jQuery is:

```
function doPollHandler(event) {
    $.post('/UploadData/InsertPolling',
        function(data) {
            alert(data); // process results here
            setTimeout(window.doPollHandler, 2000);
        });
};

$('#fileUpload').change(function () {
    doPollHandler();
});
```

I have looked at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-declare-instantiate-and-use-a-delegate

But as my method returns a bool, and I need to get the value of counter I'm stuck on how to do this.

Comment: In the static method, I assume `tCount` and `primaryCounter` don't refer to the same thing? You could just add a second `out` parameter, but that starts to look smelly. We may need more details of the code to give a succinct answer

Comment: Hi @Rhumborl I cannot use tCount as that returns the count of all records at the end, what I am trying to do is get the value of primaryCounter every 2 seconds so that the visitor can see the progress.

Comment: That's not what Rhumborl was saying. Rhumborl said you could add a *second* `out` parameter. And was hinting that if your method returns more than one thing, like it already does, consider returning a simple object with some properties to hold those values, rather than returning `bool` and having an `out` parameter. But you need the value updated before the method returns, so that won't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you understand callback using delegate

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        public delegate void Del(int message);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Del handler = DelegateMethod;
            MethodWithCallback(handler);
        }

        public static void MethodWithCallback(Del callback)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                callback(i);

            }
        }
        public static void DelegateMethod(int primaryCounter)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(primaryCounter);
        }
    }
}
```